# c++ what is CharT element in string::size?

Tags: c++, stdstring

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size

> The number of `CharT` elements in the string.

What is `CharT` element?

Comment: just "slang" for character Type elements, can be either wchar_t or char

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen No slang, but an identifier clearly defined in the linked documentation. And the second part of your comment is also wrong.

Comment: It's the template parameter name for the contained character type - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: Upvoting simply to offset the downvotes, which were not merited IMHO. It's a legit newbie question.

Comment: `std::string` is an alias for `std::basic_string<char>`, and `std::wstring` is an alias for `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`

Comment: @einpoklum especially given that the #1 Google result for "std::string::size" takes you to the linked resource

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen I think it could also be `char16_t` or `char32_t` too, am I right?

Comment: @rick yeah, char in its most general form

Comment: An object of type charT has value charT(), which in a specific case, on the other hand - as an example - can have value char().

Answer (score 8):

`std::basic_string` is a class template that is defined as

```
template< 
    class CharT, 
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>, 
    class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
> class basic_string;
```

where `CharT` is the type of character stored by the string.  So `std::basic_string::size` returns the number of `CharT` elements in the string.

Comment: How is a charT different from char?

Comment: @thegreatcoder `charT` is a placeholder type.  For a `std::string` it is `char`.  For a `std::wstring` it is a `wchar_t`.  `basic_string` works with many different character types, and `charT` is a stand in for the concrete type.

Comment: How is a basic_string different from a string apart from the fact that their placeholders can be different?

Comment: @thegreatcoder It isn't.  `std::string` isn't actually it's own class (well it is a tempalte specialization but we can ignore that for now).  What it is, is a type alias for `std::basic_string<char>`.  Same for `std::wstring`.  That is just a `sdt::basic_string<wchar_t>`.  It is the `charT` that the alias maps to.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for having these type aliases in this context in the first place?

Comment: @thegreatcoder Sure, it's convenient.  Instead of having to say `std::basic_string<char>` you just say `std::string`.