# How is charT checked for/enforced in template code?

Tags: c++, templates

I am very new to c++ and am trying to understand how "generic" types are "enforced" in templates, specifically with something like `charT`.

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681173/c-what-is-chart-element-in-stringsize) I understand that `charT` can be any char-like object, but I am wondering what the appropriate way is to check that the user actually supplied a valid `charT`.

In other words, what happens if you provide a `double` instead?  Do you just rely on the complier throwing an error when the function inevitably tries to do something invalid with the double?  Or is there a formal way to check that the supplied type is valid?

Comment: There are [type traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) which can be used together with [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error). Or since C++20 one could use a [concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints). Or the simple way, just let it be and give errors when the type is used in an unexpected way that leads to error (which might not always happen, so not really a good solution).

Comment: unfortunately there is no simple answer to your question. I am actually not sure what the standard says, but constructing a `basic_string<double>` seems to be fine, while trying to pipe it to `std::cout` produces one of those funny endless compiler messages: https://godbolt.org/z/ha58Pqah9

Comment: If you provide a `double`, the `Traits` type will be borked in some way. But seeing as you can use a custom one, or specialize `std::char_traits`, you can define almost anything to be "char-like". A concrete example could be a class that represents big-endian wide characters. Kinda rare and out there, but possible to make `std::basic_string` work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, this is can be done in C++ using type traits, `std::enable_if` and [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error), assuming that you're using pre-C++20 code. The basic principle is to check if a type has a certain property and if it doesn't, to disable a function overload or class specialization.

For example, if you want to write a function template that only makes sense for classes derived from a certain base class, you can write:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Base {};

struct Derived : public Base {};

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>>>
void foo(const T&) {
}

int main() {
    Derived d{};

    foo(d);
    //foo(1);  <-- ERROR: requirement not fulfilled

    return 0;
}
```

Here, a second, unnamed template parameter is used and assigned to the type "returned" by `std::enable_if_t` (this is shorthand for `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` to save one from typing out all that and is available as of C++14). `std::enable_if` will only have the type definition called `type` if the first parameter evaluates to `true`. In this example, we check if `std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>` is `true`. If that is the case, then `std::enable_if` will be instantiated to have a `using type = void;` declaration (if one desires different type than void, this can be passed to `std::enable_if` as a second parameter right after the `bool` parameter). Therefore, the unnamed parameter will be set to `void` and the program compiles. If, however, the first parameter evaluates to `false`, there will be no type definition in `std::enable_if`, and the function template will not be instantiated, because the type for the second parameter in our template cannot be substituted, which will merely remove the function from the overload set and not cause a compiler error. This is what SFINAE means. Of course if no other viable overload can be found, you will still get an error, but not due to the fact that the template instantiation failed.

If you uncomment the call to `foo(1)`, clang, for instance, will say:

```
<source>:15:5: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
    foo(1);
    ^~~
<source>:8:6: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'std::is_base_of_v<Base, int>' was not satisfied [with T = int]
void foo(const T&) {
```

This, of course, is much more readable that some page-long, cryptic error message arising from an error from within the function caused by some operation that simply cannot be called on an `int`.

Using C++20 [concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)), you could also write the template like so:

```
template<typename T>
requires std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>
void foo(const T&) {
}
```

Concepts greatly improve readability as template metaprogramming code can quickly get very lenghty and hard to read.

If you need to check more complex properties of a type, you can combine multiple type traits or write your own, which can get very complicated depending on what it is that you need to check.

I hope that clears things up a little bit for you!

Comment: Thanks!  So it sounds like you need to enforce type checking yourself.  Also, thanks for providing and explaining the idioms used to do so.